# Texto de fondo en textbox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Hola quería poner un texto de fondo sobre un textbox como los que se suelen poner en los formularios (como en la página de dropbox) que aparece 'Nombre' en un color mas clarito y hasta que no escribes algo no se quita. Hasta ahora había puesto que cuando tuviese el focus y estaba 'Nombre' escrito lo borrase pero mientras está seleccionado está vacio y el usuario puede olvidarse de qué campo es

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida.

Answer (score 4):

creo que te refieres al hint o marca de agua...

Puedes crear una marca de agua que puede ser agregada a cualquier textbox a traves de una propiedad. Aqui esta el codigo para la propiedad:

```
using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Windows;
   using System.Windows.Controls;
   using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
   using System.Windows.Documents;

   /// <summary>
   /// Class that provides the Watermark attached property
   /// </summary>
   public static class WatermarkService
   {
        /// <summary>
        /// Watermark Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty WatermarkProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
           "Watermark",
           typeof(object),
           typeof(WatermarkService),
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((object)null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnWatermarkChanged)));

        #region Private Fields

        /// <summary>
        /// Dictionary of ItemsControls
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly Dictionary<object, ItemsControl> itemsControls = new Dictionary<object, ItemsControl>();

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Watermark property.  This dependency property indicates the watermark for the control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d"><see cref="DependencyObject"/> to get the property from</param>
        /// <returns>The value of the Watermark property</returns>
        public static object GetWatermark(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (object)d.GetValue(WatermarkProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the Watermark property.  This dependency property indicates the watermark for the control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d"><see cref="DependencyObject"/> to set the property on</param>
        /// <param name="value">value of the property</param>
        public static void SetWatermark(DependencyObject d, object value)
        {
            d.SetValue(WatermarkProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the Watermark property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d"><see cref="DependencyObject"/> that fired the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">A <see cref="DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
        private static void OnWatermarkChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Control control = (Control)d;
            control.Loaded += Control_Loaded;

            if (d is ComboBox)
            {
                control.GotKeyboardFocus += Control_GotKeyboardFocus;
                control.LostKeyboardFocus += Control_Loaded;
            }
            else if(d is TextBox)
            {
                control.GotKeyboardFocus += Control_GotKeyboardFocus;
                control.LostKeyboardFocus += Control_Loaded;
                ((TextBox)control).TextChanged += Control_GotKeyboardFocus;
            }

            if (d is ItemsControl && !(d is ComboBox))
            {
                ItemsControl i = (ItemsControl)d;

                // for Items property  
                i.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += ItemsChanged;
                itemsControls.Add(i.ItemContainerGenerator, i);

                // for ItemsSource property  
                DependencyPropertyDescriptor prop = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, i.GetType());
                prop.AddValueChanged(i, ItemsSourceChanged);
            }
        }

        #region Event Handlers

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle the GotFocus event on the control
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">A <see cref="RoutedEventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
        private static void Control_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Control c = (Control)sender;
            if (ShouldShowWatermark(c))
            {
                ShowWatermark(c);
            }
            else
            {
                RemoveWatermark(c);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle the Loaded and LostFocus event on the control
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">A <see cref="RoutedEventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
        private static void Control_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Control control = (Control)sender;
            if (ShouldShowWatermark(control))
            {
                ShowWatermark(control);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event handler for the items source changed event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">A <see cref="EventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
        private static void ItemsSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ItemsControl c = (ItemsControl)sender;
            if (c.ItemsSource != null)
            {
                if (ShouldShowWatermark(c))
                {
                    ShowWatermark(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    RemoveWatermark(c);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ShowWatermark(c);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event handler for the items changed event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">A <see cref="ItemsChangedEventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
        private static void ItemsChanged(object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ItemsControl control;
            if (itemsControls.TryGetValue(sender, out control))
            {
                if (ShouldShowWatermark(control))
                {
                    ShowWatermark(control);
                }
                else
                {
                    RemoveWatermark(control);
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Helper Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove the watermark from the specified element
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="control">Element to remove the watermark from</param>
        private static void RemoveWatermark(UIElement control)
        {
            AdornerLayer layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(control);

            // layer could be null if control is no longer in the visual tree
            if (layer != null)
            {
                Adorner[] adorners = layer.GetAdorners(control);
                if (adorners == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                foreach (Adorner adorner in adorners)
                {
                    if (adorner is WatermarkAdorner)
                    {
                        adorner.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                        layer.Remove(adorner);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Show the watermark on the specified control
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="control">Control to show the watermark on</param>
        private static void ShowWatermark(Control control)
        {
            AdornerLayer layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(control);

            // layer could be null if control is no longer in the visual tree
            if (layer != null)
            {
                layer.Add(new WatermarkAdorner(control, GetWatermark(control)));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates whether or not the watermark should be shown on the specified control
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="c"><see cref="Control"/> to test</param>
        /// <returns>true if the watermark should be shown; false otherwise</returns>
        private static bool ShouldShowWatermark(Control c)
        {
            if (c is ComboBox)
            {
                return (c as ComboBox).Text == string.Empty;
            }
            else if (c is TextBoxBase)
            {
                return (c as TextBox).Text == string.Empty;
            }
            else if (c is ItemsControl)
            {
                return (c as ItemsControl).Items.Count == 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

La propiedad usa una clase llamada WatermarkAdorner, aquí está el código:

```
using System.Windows;
   using System.Windows.Controls;
   using System.Windows.Data;
   using System.Windows.Documents;
   using System.Windows.Media;

   /// <summary>
   /// Adorner for the watermark
   /// </summary>
   internal class WatermarkAdorner : Adorner
   {
      #region Private Fields

      /// <summary>
      /// <see cref="ContentPresenter"/> that holds the watermark
      /// </summary>
      private readonly ContentPresenter contentPresenter;

      #endregion

      #region Constructor

      /// <summary>
      /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="WatermarkAdorner"/> class
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="adornedElement"><see cref="UIElement"/> to be adorned</param>
      /// <param name="watermark">The watermark</param>
      public WatermarkAdorner(UIElement adornedElement, object watermark) :
         base(adornedElement)
      {
         this.IsHitTestVisible = false;

         this.contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter();
         this.contentPresenter.Content = watermark;
         this.contentPresenter.Opacity = 0.5;
         this.contentPresenter.Margin = new Thickness(Control.Margin.Left + Control.Padding.Left, Control.Margin.Top + Control.Padding.Top, 0, 0);

         if (this.Control is ItemsControl && !(this.Control is ComboBox))
         {
            this.contentPresenter.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            this.contentPresenter.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
         }

         // Hide the control adorner when the adorned element is hidden
         Binding binding = new Binding("IsVisible");
         binding.Source = adornedElement;
         binding.Converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter();
         this.SetBinding(VisibilityProperty, binding);
      }

      #endregion

      #region Protected Properties

      /// <summary>
      /// Gets the number of children for the <see cref="ContainerVisual"/>.
      /// </summary>
      protected override int VisualChildrenCount
      {
         get { return 1; }
      }

      #endregion

      #region Private Properties

      /// <summary>
      /// Gets the control that is being adorned
      /// </summary>
      private Control Control
      {
         get { return (Control)this.AdornedElement; }
      }

      #endregion

      #region Protected Overrides

      /// <summary>
      /// Returns a specified child <see cref="Visual"/> for the parent <see cref="ContainerVisual"/>.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="index">A 32-bit signed integer that represents the index value of the child <see cref="Visual"/>. The value of index must be between 0 and <see cref="VisualChildrenCount"/> - 1.</param>
      /// <returns>The child <see cref="Visual"/>.</returns>
      protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
      {
         return this.contentPresenter;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Implements any custom measuring behavior for the adorner.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="constraint">A size to constrain the adorner to.</param>
      /// <returns>A <see cref="Size"/> object representing the amount of layout space needed by the adorner.</returns>
      protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
      {
         // Here's the secret to getting the adorner to cover the whole control
         this.contentPresenter.Measure(Control.RenderSize);
         return Control.RenderSize;
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// When overridden in a derived class, positions child elements and determines a size for a <see cref="FrameworkElement"/> derived class. 
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="finalSize">The final area within the parent that this element should use to arrange itself and its children.</param>
      /// <returns>The actual size used.</returns>
      protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
      {
         this.contentPresenter.Arrange(new Rect(finalSize));
         return finalSize;
      }

      #endregion
   }
```

Ahora puedes poner una marca de agua en cualquier TextBox de esta forma:

```
<AdornerDecorator>
   <TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBox">
      <controls:WatermarkService.Watermark>
         <TextBlock>escribe algo aqui...</TextBlock>
      </controls:WatermarkService.Watermark>
   </TextBox>
</AdornerDecorator>
```

La marca de agua puede ser cualquier cosa que quieras (texto, imagenes ...). Esta marca de agua tambien se puede usar incluso en ComboBoxes y en ItemControls.

Esta respuesta la encontré en el [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-hint-text-placeholder-textbox-in-wpf) en ingles, porque hace un tiempo necesite hacer lo mismo y me funcionó bastante bien.

sin embargo hay otra forma mas simple en la que solo necesitas xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox  Width="250"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="SearchTermTextBox" Margin="5"/>
    <TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="escribe algo aqui..." VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="DarkGray">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=SearchTermTextBox}" Value="">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui otra alternativa mas general:

Poner esto en el `app.xaml`.
Lo que hace es que modifica el contenido de un elemento `PlaceHolderTextBox`(mas info debajo) y lo reemplaza por 2 TextBox. Uno para el texto cuando no haya nada escrito. Y el otro seria donde el usuario escribiria.

```
<Style x:Key="PlaceHolderStyle" TargetType="components:PlaceHolderTextbox">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="components:PlaceHolderTextbox">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" 
                                         Name="PlaceHolderTextBox"
                                         VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                         BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                         BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                         Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                         FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                         Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                                         Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceHolderText}"
                                         Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                         HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                         VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                         Foreground="{TemplateBinding PlaceHolderForeground}"
                                         Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                                </TextBox>

                                <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
                                         Name="InputTextBox"
                                         Background="Transparent"
                                         HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                         VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                         BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                         BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                         VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                         Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                         Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                         FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                         Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                                         Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"></TextBox>

                            </Grid>

                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Agregar esta clase dentro de una carpeta llamada `Components`. Lo que hace que cuando el usuario escriba, el textbox que hace la funcion de [placeholder](http://www.comocreartuweb.com/curso-de-html/formularios-con-html5/placeholder.html) desaparezca haciendo que el texto sea igual al background del textbox y solamente dejando el texto del textbox donde el usuario escribe.

```
    public class PlaceHolderTextbox : UserControl
    {


        public PlaceHolderTextbox()
        {

        }


        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            var placeHolder = FindChild<TextBox>(this, "PlaceHolderTextBox");
            var InputTextBox = FindChild<TextBox>(this, "InputTextBox");

            InputTextBox.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {

                if (InputTextBox.Text?.Length == 0)
                {
                    placeHolder.Foreground = PlaceHolderForeground;
                }
                else
                {
                    placeHolder.Foreground = Background;
                }

            };

        }


        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(PlaceHolderTextbox), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));



        public SolidColorBrush PlaceHolderForeground
        {
            get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(PlaceHolderForegroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PlaceHolderForegroundProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PlaceHolderForeground.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceHolderForegroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PlaceHolderForeground", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(PlaceHolderTextbox), new PropertyMetadata( new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(204,204,204))));



        public string PlaceHolderText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceHolderTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PlaceHolderTextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PlaceHolderText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PlaceHolderTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PlaceHolderText", typeof(string), typeof(PlaceHolderTextbox), new PropertyMetadata(defaultValue: String.Empty));


        public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
  where T : DependencyObject
        {
            // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
            if (parent == null) return null;

            T foundChild = null;

            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                // If the child is not of the request child type child
                T childType = child as T;
                if (childType == null)
                {
                    // recursively drill down the tree
                    foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                    // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                    if (foundChild != null) break;
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
                {
                    var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                    // If the child's name is set for search
                    if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                    {
                        // if the child's name is of the request name
                        foundChild = (T)child;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // child element found.
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return foundChild;
        }
    }
```

Aqui la forma de como utilizarla:

```
<Window x:Class="Page1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:namespace:Proyecto2"
        xmlns:components="clr-namespace:namespace:Proyecto2.Components"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        TitlebarHeight="0"
        Title="Pagina" Height="300" Width="585.366">

        <component:PlaceHolderTextbox
            Style="{StaticResource PlaceHolderStyle}"
            Height="30"
            Width="500"
            Foreground="Black"
            PlaceHolderText="Nombre"
            Background="Grey"
            PlaceHolderForeground="#CCC"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            >

        </component:PlaceHolderTextbox>

</Window>
```

Mas info sobre [FindChild en estackoverflow en ingle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type)s.